# how to parse the children array using json in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

In this i need to get the elements from children array which will be in below mentioned url and i need to get the children array from all 11 objects can anyone help me how to implement this ?

```
   let url = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cwqUAMjKGa?indent=2"
    var detailsArray :[[String: AnyObject]] = []
    var productName = [String]()
    var childrenArray :[[String: AnyObject]] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        downloadJsonWithURL()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    func downloadJsonWithURL() {
        let url = NSURL(string: self.url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
                 self.detailsArray = (jsonObj!.value(forKey: "data") as? [[String: AnyObject]])!
                print(self.detailsArray)
                for item in self.detailsArray{
                    if let detailDict = item as? NSDictionary {
                        if let name = detailDict.value(forKey: "name"){
                            self.productName.append(name as! String)
                        }

                    }
                }

                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    print(self.productName)
                    print(self.childrenArray)
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try out this :**

```
    func downloadJsonWithURL() {
            let url = NSURL(string: self.url)
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
                if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
                     self.detailsArray = (jsonObj!.value(forKey: "data") as? [[String: AnyObject]])!
                    print(self.detailsArray)
                    for item in self.detailsArray{
                        if let detailDict = item as? [String:Any] {
                            if let name = detailDict["name"] as? String {
                                self.productName.append(name as! String)
                            }

                       if let children = detailDict["children
"] as? [Any] {
                                self.childrenArray.append(children)
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                        print(self.productName)
                        print(self.childrenArray)
                    })
                }
            }).resume()
        }
```

Comment: its working but getting only 11 th object children array but i need to get all children array

Comment: have updated my answer , yes because you have iterate the loop over array so you have to append the every data otherwise it will only show you last data . please check it my updated answer

Comment: while you are coding in swift , do not use any objective c type syntax like NSDictionary and NSArray and all . use purelly swift syntax .
just my suggestion

Comment: kk bro thanks i am new to swift 3 so i don't know @GOPAL VASANI

Comment: put break point on this line 
if let children . and see it will goes into braces or not ?

Comment: sorry bro in children also products dict is there in that i need to get names in it @GOPAL VASANI

Comment: ok you can again use the for loop same as you did for self.detailsArray

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149359/discussion-between-vamsi-krishna-and-gopal-vasani).

Answer (score 0):

iterate the detailsArray and for key "children" append the data to childrenArray

```
     for item in self.detailsArray {
            if let detailDict = item as? [String: Any] {
                if let child = detailDict["children"] {
                    self. childrenArray.append(child)
                }
            }
        }
```